# Is there a way to display the error messages to the side of the text field for Model Forms?

Tags: django, django-forms

I am us ing django Model Forms. When it catches an error it display right on top of the text field. Is there a way I could make it display it to the side of the text box instead?

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing your using one of Django's built in ways to display your form (i.e. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/#displaying-a-form-using-a-template). This is great, in that it makes it really easy to display a form with a single line, such as `{{ form.as_p }}`, however, by doing this you're giving up all of your control over how the form gets rendered. If you want that control back, you're going to have to write the HTML yourself.

That is, you'll need to do something like:

```
{% for field in form %}
    <p>{% if field.error %} {{ field.error }} {% endif %}</p>
    <p>{{ field.label }}</p>
    <p>{{ field }}</p>
{% endfor %}
```

Of course, you'll need to change the formatting to suite your needs, but you can now directly change the HTML, and add classes or id's (to use in CSS) if you nee something more advanced.

Comment: This does not seem to work. No error message can be displayed.

Answer (score 1):

Those *error messages* appearing under the widgets are just normal html elements which you can modify it's output with CSS. Take a read at [Styling required or erroneous form rows](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/forms/api/#styling-required-or-erroneous-form-rows).

Hope this helps!